# Why I get "FATAL: password authentication failed for user postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker, timescaledb, table-plus

I set up docker image for and a timescaledb postgres database.

The tutorial states to run "docker run -d --name timescaledb -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password timescale/timescaledb:2.0.0-pg12" for initial  local setup.

I am trying to connect the database to a tableplus GUI which asks for Connection Name, Host, Port, User and Password. From the timescale tutorial above I have entered-
Name: timescaledb
Host: localhost
Port: 5432
User: postgres
Password: password

I am receiving "FATAL: password authentication failed for user postgres" when trying to connect. Any assistance would be appreciated.
[TablePlus Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9ui3.png)

Comment: I wonder if that is the error message you get. The `Name` that you provide is usually the database name, not the name of the container, so in this case you should probably use `postgres`

Comment: Look in the PostgreSQL server log file for a possibly more detailed error message.